# Can I run an R Shiny app that is on a Github Enterprise repo?

Tags: r, github, shiny

My company recently signed up for Github enterprise. I'm in the process of moving my Shiny apps there and can't quite figure out how to launch the app.

The function runGitHub calls:
https://github.com/repoName, but I somehow need it to point to:
https://github.companyName.org/repoName

Is this possible?
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the help for `runGitHub`:

```
The functions ‘runGitHub()’ and ‘runGist()’ are
     based on ‘runUrl()’
```

so the solution is "use `runUrl()`".

The code in `runGitHub` has `github.com` hard-coded into it:

```
function (repo, username = getOption("github.user"), ref = "master", 
    subdir = NULL, destdir = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (grepl("/", repo)) {
        res <- strsplit(repo, "/")[[1]]
        if (length(res) != 2) 
            stop("'repo' must be of the form 'username/repo'")
        username <- res[1]
        repo <- res[2]
    }
    url <- paste("https://github.com/", username, "/", repo, 
        "/archive/", ref, ".tar.gz", sep = "")
    runUrl(url, subdir = subdir, destdir = destdir, ...)
}
```

If your enterprise github has the same path structure  (ie `/repo/archive/thing.tar.gz`) then maybe suggest to `shiny` devs to have a "host" argument with default `github.com`. Or just make the URL and call `runUrl`.